# Пустые места в категории товара woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Помогите, как исправить, появляются пустые места в категории товаров.  Приложу скриншоты. [image: нет двух товаров, их переносит на строку ниже]
Как это можно исправить, очень нужно, спасибо!

Сам сайт: https://www.floratheory.com/product-category/preserved-roses/

Comment: Верстка кривая. Первые два товара имеют бОльшую высоту, чем третий, поэтому четвёртый залазит под третий.

Comment: Править по картинке тяжело, дайте ссылку на сайт, можно попробовать тогда.

Comment: Вот сайт https://www.floratheory.com/product-category/preserved-roses/

Comment: @KAGGDesign вот https://www.floratheory.com/product-category/preserved-roses/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так. Добавьте в style.css вашей темы

```
.tcol-md-4.tcol-sm-4.tcol-xs-6.tcol-ss-12.kad_product {
    height: 349px;
}
```